# SQL JOIN to SELECT - is there an ActiveRecord way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have an SQL statement like this. Is this type of statement possible entirely or mostly in ActiveRecord?

```sql
UPDATE users
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, count(*) AS num
  FROM posts
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS counts ON users.id = counts.user_id
SET users.publications = counts.num
WHERE users.publications != counts.num;
```

1. How can I do the JOIN from a table "users" to the results of a SELECT subquery that's been grouped by one of the selected values?
2. Can I alias the join so i can compare values between the `users` table and the join?

I'm having a hard time searching for this because I don't know the term to call a JOIN that's not a join between tables, but a join from a table to a specially formatted group of results. I don't think AR's magic can work with that, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Everything is possible with AR especially using AREL - I find it cumbersome when SQL is more suited in the form of the view - but it can be done.

Comment: seems like have a field on users called publications which is the number of posts they have. why not drop that column and dynamically grab the counts ? `@users = User.joins(: posts).group('posts.user_id').select('users.*, COUNT(*) as publications')`

Comment: @dbugger while I can agree Raw SQL can be beneficial, and may be in this instance, I do love me some Arel especially when the queries need some level of dynamics and as you mentioned everything can be accomplished with Arel (albeit obtuse and esoteric at times)

Comment: @engineersmnky - I simply fail to understand the desire to write obtuse and esoteric code when you have ALREADY created working SQL,

Comment: @dbugger only 2 good reasons I know of. First as I mentioned is dynamics, if I need variable substitutions, conditional joins, etc. Second is portability. While not always a guarantee (this question being case in point) when used appropriately, where we don't actively bastardize Arel's capabilities, Arel queries are highly portable supporting the different syntax idiosyncrasies between SQL flavors without any change in code. Take for instance basic things like inequality ( `!=` v `<>`) or table quoting styles (`\`table_name\`` v `[table_name]`)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your models are related like user has_many posts and post belongs_to user.

In this case, you would be better advised to add a column called posts_count and change the relationship in User to `has_many :posts, counter_cache: true`.

This will keep a count of a user's posts in the User model, in the posts_count field, automatically updated whenever a user creates a new post. If you really need it to be called `publications`, add `def publications; posts_count; end` to the user model.

When adding this counter cache, you will need to initialize it for all the existing users. This is a one-time operation, so you can do it from the Rails console like this: `User.all.each{|u| u.reset_counters(u.id, :posts_count)}`.

Comment: Thanks @Les, I hadn't considered `counter_cache`. Here's a question: our User has ~15 associations like `post` (not all has_many, but most) that we want to keep track of. I assume there is a cost to adding counter_cache columns for all of them... would you advise doing it like that, for a db with ~20k users, ~1M posts, and varying (but smaller) numbers of the other associated objects?

Comment: Also, what are the chances of a `counter_cache`'s count becoming corrupt?

Comment: There is a very small cost to counter_cache, but if you want this data, you'll incur the cost somewhere... better to use the Rails method, so you don't have to wonder (as in your question) if you have implemented this correctly. Counter cache will not become corrupt since it's updated within a transaction when the Post is created or destroyed. Empirically, I have noticed that updating the counter cache behaves like a standard callback, so it does not update when the non-callback-triggering methods are called (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks)

Answer (score 2):

Using Arel you can hack together any valid and/or invalid SQL statements; however more complex statements generally require using classes you wouldn't think to use (or make reasonable sense in the code) *See Notes below.

For instance you can construct your desired SQL using:

```
users = Arel::Table.new('users') # User.arel_table
posts = Arel::Table.new('posts') # Post.arel_table
counts = Arel::Table.new('counts')

subquery = Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(
  # This could be converted to 
  # Post.select(:user_id, Arel.star.count.as('num')).group(:user_id).arel
  posts.project(posts[:user_id],Arel.star.count.as('num')).group(posts[:user_id]),
  counts.name)

upd_stmt = Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(users.name,
  Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(subquery,subquery.create_on(users[:id].eq(counts[:user_id])))
)

updater = Arel::UpdateManager.new
updater.table(upd_stmt)
updater.set({users[:publications] => counts[:num]})
updater.where(users[:publications].not_eq(counts[:num]))
```

Then `updater.to_sql` will produce:

```
UPDATE users 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      posts.user_id, 
      COUNT(*) AS num 
    FROM 
      posts 
    GROUP BY 
      posts.user_id) counts ON users.id = counts.user_id 
SET publications = counts.num 
WHERE 
  users.publications != counts.num
```

Whether or not this is functional I cannot say but it does produce the desired SQL.

**Note**: As you can see we used a `UnaryOperation` to create the top half of the UPDATE statement. This is obviously odd because these operations are generally for basics like `- 1` or `+ 1` but understanding that when visited this class will construct SQL as `[operator] [operand]` we can utilize this understanding (no matter how debasing it might be) to construct other statements.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky. Is it possible to use a plain AR `User.update_all(complex_arel_statement)` instead of using a `UnaryOperation`? In any case, that's not as verbose as I was afraid it would be. A lot of what i was missing is the `InnerJoin` on the `subquery, subquery.create_on` with `TableAlias`.

Comment: @nimmolo unfortunately reviewing the [Source](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) it does not appear that you can manipulate `update_all` as it creates and executes the arel inside that method. At least not with the desired SQL. You could do it with individual subqueries e.g. `users.publication_counts = (SELECT count...` but that could have performance impacts.

Answer (score 0):

What database is used in your project?
In SQL Server the syntax is like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET users.publications = counts.num
from users as A
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) AS num
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS counts ON users.id = counts.user_id
WHERE users.publications != counts.num
```

I believe it is ANSI SQL but I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks @fransiscofjs. Our db is mysql. Our current sql query above works, but i'm wondering if I can rewrite it in AR.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).